# retain 0 from real value

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I'm fetching data from an excel sheet using excel interop and plotting the data to a new workbook. I noticed the zeros where removed from the original data. how can I retain the exact same value from the source data to a new workbook.

actual data: 0833103156
output: 833103156

I tried each below syntax but same output.

```cs
string data = wsraw.Cells [intLoop, 1].Value;
string data = wsraw.Cells [intLoop, 1].Text;
```

Comment: Please clarify which library you're using, and what type of file this is.

Comment: hi @DiplomacyNotWar library I'm using using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; file is in .xlsx format (excel file)

Comment: By "actual data" you mean what is shown in excel? That is dependent on the format of the cell. Maybe you need to copy the format of the cell too? The data that excel stores internally does not contain the leading zero if it is stored as a number.

Comment: Yes. exact data shown that is shown in excel